# Stop moving elements when zoom the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a lot of effort and research, I finally found a way to resize the elements on the page while zooming and it works correctly (All sizes remain intact if you zoom the page by using "vh" and "vw" instead of "px" or "em" units).

Now the problem is when I zoom in on the page the elements move toward the bottom-right of the page.

Here is 100% zoom:

[image]

And when we zoom the page up to 500%:

[image]

We don't want to move those elements when users zoom in on the page. How can I stop that unexpected movement?

**There should be a pure CSS solution.**

Here is the code:

**Note: Please do not test the code here or on CodePen! For some reason, zooming works fine if you create separate HTML, CSS and JS files and test it on chrome only! When I tested it on Stack Snippet and CodePen it didn't work. I've attached the files to have a look in the link below**

http://s7.picofile.com/d/8378155676/f18acc00-cccf-4b33-a2d8-6438d7275ddf/loader.zip

```js
var value = 0;
var pos = 0;
var progressHidden = false;
var delay = 40;
var progressEl = $('progress');

// set interval
var timer = setInterval(progress, 70);

function progress() {
  
  // run counter
  value++;
  if (value < 99) {
    progressEl.val(value);
    pos = 1 - (value/100);
  } else if(value < (delay + 100) ) {
    progressEl.val(99);
    pos = 0;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }
  
  // update background
  progressEl.css('background-position', '0 '+ pos +'em');
  
  // show/hide progress
  if(!progressHidden && value >= 100) {
    progressEl.addClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = true;
    
  } else if(progressHidden && value < 100) {
    progressEl.val(0);
    progressEl.removeClass("hidden");
    progressHidden = false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 0vw;
  height: 1.5727391874180865vh;
  margin: 0vh 0 0 1vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.6525198938992043vh, orangered 2.6525198938992043vh, orangered  5.305039787798409vh);
  border-radius: 3vh;
  animation: roll 10s linear infinite;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.6510416666666666vw 1.3106159895150722vh rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0vh 0.06510416666666667vw 0vh rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -0.3255208333333333vw 0.3931847968545216vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.1953125vw 0.2621231979030144vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#progress-bar:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13.020833333333334vw;
  height: 2.6212319790301444vh;
  border: 0.1310615989515072vh solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
  border-radius: 3vh; 
  content: "";
  left: -0.3255208333333333vw;
  top:  -0.6553079947575361vh;
  z-index: -1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  0% {
    width: 0vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 12.369791666666666vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>load</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
I have another project that acts as expected and doesn't move the page content. feel free to ask for the files and whole code(I just put CSS here):

```
*{
  overflow: hidden;

}

.container {

  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number-ticker {
  position:absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
   justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 12vw;
  left:6vh;
  color: #D9D9D9;
  font-size: 80vh;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.number-ticker .digit {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: margin-top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @Caharpuka  yeah... but not always... sometimes a mess is the only thing that could save you...

Comment: I'm working on a web app and I need to put this on an iFrame in Articulate Storyline ... If zooming function works I lose the content of the iFrame because the contents of the storyline don't follow the page zoom ... and...

Answer (score 0):

Working CSS:

```
 .container {
      overflow: hidden;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    #progress-bar {
     position:absolute;
       justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
       left: 10vw;
      top:  10vh;
      border: 0vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      width: 0vw;
      height: 1.5727391874180865vh;
      margin: 0vh 0 0 1vw;
      background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red, red 2.6525198938992043vh, orangered 2.6525198938992043vh, orangered  5.305039787798409vh);
      border-radius: 3vh;
      animation: roll 10s linear infinite;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0.6510416666666666vw 1.3106159895150722vh rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 0vh 0.06510416666666667vw 0vh rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -0.3255208333333333vw 0.3931847968545216vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.1953125vw 0.2621231979030144vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    #progress-bar:after {
      position: absolute;
      width: 13.020833333333334vw;
      height: 2.6212319790301444vh;
      border: 0.1310615989515072vh solid rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
      background: rgba(13, 13, 13, 0.7);
      border-radius: 3vh; 
      content: "";
      left: -0.3255208333333333vw;
      top:  -0.6553079947575361vh;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes roll {
      0% {
        width: 0vw;
      }
      100% {
        width: 12.369791666666666vw;
      }
    }
```